# Bulk insert nested xml with foreign key as identity column of first table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, azure-sql-database, sqlxml

I have an xml as follows:

```
<Records>
  <Record>
    <Name>Best of Pop</Name>
    <Studio>ABC studio</Studio>
    <Artists>
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>John</ArtistName>
        <Age>36</Age>            
      </Artist> 
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>Jessica</ArtistName>
        <Age>20</Age>            
      </Artist>
    </Artists>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Name>Nursery rhymes</Name>
    <Studio>XYZ studio</Studio>
    <Artists>
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>Judy</ArtistName>
        <Age>10</Age>            
      </Artist> 
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>Rachel</ArtistName>
        <Age>15</Age>            
      </Artist>
    </Artists>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

This file may contain millions of records. My MS SQL database, running on [Azure SQL Database](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/), has the following 2 tables to store these records:

1. `Record` (RecordId [PK, identity, auto-increment], Name, Studio)
2. `Artist` (RecordId [Foreign Key refers Record.RecordId], ArtistName, Age)

Is it possible to bulk insert records into the `Record` table, get the RecordIds and then bulk insert the artist information into the `Artist` table in a single traversal of the xml using the xml nodes approach?

I have been searching for an efficient way to do this for a long time but in vain.

I have tried approaches similar to the ones described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285679/get-scope-identity-value-when-inserting-bulk-records-for-sql-tabletype) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469688/sql-server-bulk-insert-with-foreign-key-parameter-not-existant-in-txt-file-erd), but I'm not able to get to the solution.

Any pointers in the direction of the solution will be of great help.

**Update**:
@srutzky: Thanks for the solution. This works exactly as I wanted. But there is one catch. I have to use the nodes approach for the solution. I have changed the first part of the query. But I'm stuck in the 2nd half. Here's what I have got up to.

```
DECLARE @Record TABLE (RecordId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                       Name NVARCHAR(400) UNIQUE,
                       Studio NVARCHAR(400));
DECLARE @Artist TABLE (ArtistId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                       RecordId INT NOT NULL,
                       ArtistName NVARCHAR(400), Age INT);

INSERT INTO @Record (Name, Studio)
   SELECT  T.c.value(N'(Name/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(400)'),
           T.c.value(N'(Studio/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(400)')
 FROM @ImportData.nodes('/Records/Record') T(c);

SELECT * FROM @Record
```

Could you please help me out with the 2nd part? I'm new to this xml handling approach.

**UPDATE2**: And I got it.... I racked my brains for a couple of hours, tried a few things and finally arrived at the solution.

```
DECLARE @Record TABLE (RecordId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                       Name NVARCHAR(400) UNIQUE,
                       Studio NVARCHAR(400));
DECLARE @Artist TABLE (ArtistId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                       RecordId INT NOT NULL,
                       ArtistName NVARCHAR(400), 
                       Age INT);

INSERT INTO @Record (Name, Studio)
   SELECT  T.c.value(N'(Name/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(400)'),
           T.c.value(N'(Studio/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(400)')
 FROM @ImportData.nodes('/Records/Record') T(c);

INSERT INTO @Artist (RecordId, ArtistName, Age)
    SELECT  (SELECT RecordId FROM @Record WHERE Name=T.c.value(N'(../../Name/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(400)')),
            T.c.value(N'(ArtistName/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(400)'),
           T.c.value(N'(Age/text())[1]', 'INT')
 FROM @ImportData.nodes('/Records/Record/Artists/Artist') T(c);

 SELECT * FROM @Record
 SELECT * FROM @Artist
```

@srutzky: Thanks a ton for pointing me in the right direction. Any suggestions to improve this solution are welcome.

Comment: Why do you need it in a single traversal?  Also, please show us what you already have.

Comment: Is the <Name> element within <Record> unique?

Comment: @srutzky: Yes the name is unique.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I just need to do it in a efficient manner, not necessarily in a single traversal. I tried out what's described in the 2 links I shared previously, but was able to only get half-way through to the solution. The results were far from what was intended, so haven't shared anything else.

Comment: @nikhil : sorry, I didn't see your comments and updates. Using "@" with a name doesn't work in the body of a question or answer. You need to comment on my answer. Why do you need to use nodes? That is fine, but will likely be less efficient. But I will update my answer with that in mind. Please use the comments there to communicate :).

Comment: @nikhil : I have updated my answer. You don't need the nested `SELECT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done in a single pass anyway as you can't insert into two tables in the same DML statement (well, outside of Triggers and the OUTPUT clause, neither of which would help here). But it can be done efficiently in two passes. The fact at the `<Name>` element within `<Record>` is unique is the key, as that allows us to use the `Record` table as the lookup table for the second pass (i.e. when we are getting the `Artist` rows).

First, you need (well, *should*) create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `Record (Name ASC)`. In my example below I am using a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, but that is only due to my using a table variable instead of a temp table to make the example code more easily rerunnable (without needing an explicit IF EXISTS DROP at the top). This index will help the performance of the second pass.

The example uses OPENXML as that will most likely be more efficient that using the `.nodes()` function since the same document needs to be traversed twice. The last parameter for the `OPENXML` function, the `2`, specifies that the document is "Element-based" since the default parsing is looking for "Attribute-based".

```sql
DECLARE @DocumentID INT, @ImportData XML;

SET @ImportData = N'
<Records>
  <Record>
    <Name>Best of Pop</Name>
    <Studio>ABC studio</Studio>
    <Artists>
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>John</ArtistName>
        <Age>36</Age>            
      </Artist> 
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>Jessica</ArtistName>
        <Age>20</Age>            
      </Artist>
    </Artists>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Name>Nursery rhymes</Name>
    <Studio>XYZ studio</Studio>
    <Artists>
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>Judy</ArtistName>
        <Age>10</Age>            
      </Artist> 
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>Rachel</ArtistName>
        <Age>15</Age>            
      </Artist>
    </Artists>
  </Record>
</Records>';


DECLARE @Record TABLE (RecordId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                       Name NVARCHAR(400) UNIQUE,
                       Studio NVARCHAR(400));
DECLARE @Artist TABLE (ArtistId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                       RecordId INT NOT NULL,
                       ArtistName NVARCHAR(400), Age INT);

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocumentID OUTPUT, @ImportData;

-- First pass: extract "Record" rows
INSERT INTO @Record (Name, Studio)
   SELECT Name, Studio
   FROM   OPENXML (@DocumentID, N'/Records/Record', 2) 
             WITH (Name    NVARCHAR(400)  './Name/text()', 
                   Studio  NVARCHAR(400)  './Studio/text()');


-- Second pass: extract "Artist" rows
INSERT INTO @Artist (RecordId, ArtistName, Age)
   SELECT rec.RecordId, art.ArtistName, art.Age
   FROM   OPENXML (@DocumentID, N'/Records/Record/Artists/Artist', 2) 
             WITH (Name        NVARCHAR(400)  '../../Name/text()',
                   ArtistName  NVARCHAR(400)  './ArtistName/text()', 
                   Age         INT  './Age/text()') art
   INNER JOIN @Record rec
           ON rec.[Name] = art.[Name];


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocumentID;
-------------------

SELECT * FROM @Record ORDER BY [RecordID];
SELECT * FROM @Artist ORDER BY [RecordID];
```

References:

- [OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx)
- [sp_xml_preparedocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187367.aspx)
- [sp_xml_removedocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190353.aspx)

**EDIT:**
With the new requirement to use the `.nodes()` function instead of `OPENXML`, the following will work:

```sql
DECLARE @ImportData XML;

SET @ImportData = N'
<Records>
  <Record>
    <Name>Best of Pop</Name>
    <Studio>ABC studio</Studio>
    <Artists>
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>John</ArtistName>
        <Age>36</Age>            
      </Artist> 
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>Jessica</ArtistName>
        <Age>20</Age>            
      </Artist>
    </Artists>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Name>Nursery rhymes</Name>
    <Studio>XYZ studio</Studio>
    <Artists>
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>Judy</ArtistName>
        <Age>10</Age>            
      </Artist> 
      <Artist>
        <ArtistName>Rachel</ArtistName>
        <Age>15</Age>            
      </Artist>
    </Artists>
  </Record>
</Records>';

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Record') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #Record;
END;
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Artist') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #Artist;
END;

CREATE TABLE #Record (RecordId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                      Name NVARCHAR(400) UNIQUE,
                      Studio NVARCHAR(400));
CREATE TABLE #Artist (ArtistId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                      RecordId INT NOT NULL,
                      ArtistName NVARCHAR(400),
                      Age INT);


-- First pass: extract "Record" rows
INSERT INTO #Record (Name, Studio)
   SELECT col.value(N'(./Name/text())[1]', N'NVARCHAR(400)') AS [Name],
          col.value(N'(./Studio/text())[1]', N'NVARCHAR(400)') AS [Studio]
   FROM   @ImportData.nodes(N'/Records/Record') tab(col);


-- Second pass: extract "Artist" rows
;WITH artists AS
(
   SELECT col.value(N'(../../Name/text())[1]', N'NVARCHAR(400)') AS [RecordName],
          col.value(N'(./ArtistName/text())[1]', N'NVARCHAR(400)') AS [ArtistName],
          col.value(N'(./Age/text())[1]', N'INT') AS [Age]
   FROM   @ImportData.nodes(N'/Records/Record/Artists/Artist') tab(col)
)
INSERT INTO #Artist (RecordId, ArtistName, Age)
   SELECT rec.RecordId, art.ArtistName, art.Age
   FROM artists art
   INNER JOIN #Record rec
           ON rec.[Name] = art.RecordName;

-- OR --
-- INSERT INTO #Artist (RecordId, ArtistName, Age)
   SELECT rec.RecordId,
          col.value(N'(./ArtistName/text())[1]', N'NVARCHAR(400)') AS [ArtistName],
          col.value(N'(./Age/text())[1]', N'INT') AS [Age]
   FROM   @ImportData.nodes(N'/Records/Record/Artists/Artist') tab(col)
   INNER JOIN #Record rec
           ON rec.Name = col.value(N'(../../Name/text())[1]', N'NVARCHAR(400)');

-------------------

SELECT * FROM #Record ORDER BY [RecordID];
SELECT * FROM #Artist ORDER BY [RecordID];
```

There are two options for inserting into `#Artist` shown above. The first uses a CTE to abstract the XML extraction away from the INSERT / SELECT query. The other is a simplified version, similar to your query in **UPDATE 2** of the question.

Comment: Thanks again for the optimization. I have to use nodes because we're dealing with a SQL Azure db. It's not SQL server. OpenXML does not work there.

Comment: @nikhil : You are welcome. The fact that this runs on Azure SQL DB is a critically important detail so I edited the question to add that info as well as adding a tag for it.

Comment: That was nice of you. Thanks. I'll keep these thing in mind for the future.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky for the first table if it is an insert in an actual table then how can we query and get the pk value and insert into another table. Plz advise.

Comment: @Zaker Hi. Not sure I understand the difference from what I have posted here. What do you mean by "actual" table? The tables being inserted into shown in my answer are all actual tables. In my examples here I am joining a value in the XML to the first table to get the PK value to insert into the second table.